# WF4.0: ResumeBookmark timeout after 64 times successful trials using WorkflowHostingEndpoint

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, bookmarks

This is a very interesting issue: I am writing an activity to receive messages from outside and process in its child activities. I create a bookmark in the activity to wait. When there comes a new message, I will resume the bookmark using WorkflowHostingEndpoint and process it. Finally create the bookmark again to wait for another new coming message. But the problem is: this works fine until I processed 64 messages (I tried several times, always 64 good processing then failed). After that all the ResumeBookmark calls will end up with Timeout exception. I tried to use WorkflowApplication to host my activity and it works OK. I'm rather appreciated with any helpful answers. Thanks.

Comment: Sharing some of the code might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you start additional instances with every message? There is a limit on the maximum number of active instances at a time. If you reach the limit, your request for another instance waits until the limit is not reached anymore but you get a Timeout before this happens.

The default value depends on the number of processors you have.

You may modify the limits in your app/web.config:

```
<behaviors> 
  <serviceBehaviors> 
    <behavior name="CalculatorServiceBehavior">
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="16" maxConcurrentInstances="1000"/> 
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

See [ServiceThrottling on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731379.aspx) for more information.